# Terraform azurerm_network_interface - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: azure, terraform

Using terraform to build out a set of azure vms; cannot for the life of me figure out this error. I've wandered into a maze of twisty passages all alike ...

This code produces the following error. Doesn't look wrong, but is.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "TW-PROD-AZR-NETDB-network" {
  name = "TW-PROD-AZR-NETDB-Network"
  address_space = ["10.240.0.0/16"]
  location = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.TW-PROD-AZR-NETDB.name}"

resource "azurerm_subnet" "TW-PROD-AZR-NETDB-subnet1-private" {
  name = "TW-PROD-AZR-NETDB-subnet1-private"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.TW-PROD-AZR-NETDB.name}"
  virutal_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.TW-PROD-AZR-NETDB-network.name}"
  address_prefix = "10.240.1.0/24"
}

# Create VNIC DB01
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "TW-PROD-AZR-DB01-NIC01" {
  name = "TW-PROD-AZR-DB01-NIC01"
  location = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = "TW-PROD-AZR-NETD"
  network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.TW-PROD-AZRDB-SG.id}"

  ip_configuration {
    name = "TW-PROD-AZR-DB01-NIC01-CONFIG"
    subnet_id = "${azurerm_subnet.TW-PROD-AZR-NETDB-subnet1-private.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id = "TW-PROD-AZR-DB01-IP"
  }

  tags {
    Env = "Production"
    Group = "NETDB"
  }
}
```

- resource 'azurerm_network_interface.TW-PROD-AZR-DB01-NIC01' config: unknown resource 'azurerm_subnet.TW-PROD-AZR-NETDB-subnet1-private' referenced in variable azurerm_subnet.TW-PROD-AZR-NETDB-subnet1-private.id
  ￼

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your tf file.

1.resource `azurerm_virtual_network` lost `}` at the end.

2.In resource `azurerm_subnet`, vir`ut`al_network_name is wrong, it should be vir`tu`al_network_name.

The following tf file works for me. Note: For test easily, I delete NSG and public IP.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "TW-PROD-AZR-NETDB-network" {
  name = "TW-PROD-AZR-NETDB-Network"
  address_space = ["10.240.0.0/16"]
  location = "West US"
  resource_group_name = "TW-PROD-AZR-NETD"
}
resource "azurerm_subnet" "TW-PROD-AZR-NETDB-subnet1-private" {
  name = "TW-PROD-AZR-NETDB-subnet1-private"
  resource_group_name = "TW-PROD-AZR-NETD"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.TW-PROD-AZR-NETDB-network.name}"
  address_prefix = "10.240.1.0/24"
}

# Create VNIC DB01
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "TW-PROD-AZR-DB01-NIC01" {
  name = "TW-PROD-AZR-DB01-NIC01"
  location = "West US"
  resource_group_name = "TW-PROD-AZR-NETD"


  ip_configuration {
    name = "TW-PROD-AZR-DB01-NIC01-CONFIG"
    subnet_id = "${azurerm_subnet.TW-PROD-AZR-NETDB-subnet1-private.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"

  }

  tags {
    Env = "Production"
    Group = "TW-PROD-AZR-NETD"
  }
}
```

If you use Compare tool, you will see the difference clear.

[image]

Comment: @BrianDunbar For similar issue, you could use Compare tool to check difference.